# Cordova Android App with Web Service

Tags: android, web-services, cordova

i developed an App with cordova that communicates with a WebService. It works with Ios, but if I try to use it with Android, at first WebService calling, it doesn't work...

here my code:

```
doLogin: function (user, password, successCallback, failCallback) {
                    jApp.gui.showWait();
                    var parametri = "NomeUtente=" + user + "&Password=" + password;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: serviceUrl + "Login.ashx?" + parametri,
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        dataFilter: null,
                        async: true,
                        success: <-- I think it stops here
                            function (r) {
                            jApp.gui.hideWait();
                            if (r.Success)
                            {
                                //salvo le credenziali su file
                                var strLogin = '{"user":"' + user + '","password":"' + password + '"}';
                                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(pathApp, function (dir) {
                                    dir.getFile("login.json", {create: true}, function (file) {
                                        file.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                                            fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length);
                                            var blob = new Blob([strLogin], { type: 'text/plain' });
                                                fileWriter.onwriteend = function (evt) {
                                                successCallback(r);
                                            }
                                            fileWriter.write(blob);

                                        }, failCallback);
                                    });
                                });
                                //TODO: salvarsi user e pwd?
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                alert(r.ErrorMessage);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (e) {
                            jApp.gui.hideWait();
                            alert("errore");
                        }
                    });
```

Thank you

Comment: Which version of Cordova are you using? Have you set the permissions to access internet in the config files?

Comment: My version il 5.3.3. In the Config.xml I added
<access origin="*" />
and on IOS systems it works